# why am I not getting the tokens created when I tell django to do it?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a password reset in Django, but once the input finds the email in the database then send an email with their token similar to `http://localhost:8000/account/account-recovery/process-reset/7d498a893edc45aa921a48f81f4826d3`. it works amazingly until here, but after checking in Django shell the function that checks tokens. I have another problem it returns False that means no token was generated in the database.

```
>>> verify_password_token('7d498a893edc45aa921a48f81f4826d3')
False
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=False, unique=True, null=False)
    signup_confirmation = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    @receiver(pre_save, sender='account.User')
    def generate_token(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.token = str(uuid4()).replace('-', '')
```

helper.py

```
def generate_password_reset_token(request, email):
    try:
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(email=email)
    except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
        return False
    get_user_model().objects.filter(email=user).delete()
    created = get_user_model().objects.create(email=user, token=user.token)
    email_subject = 'account recovery code'
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    html_message = render_to_string('email/account-recovery.html', {
        'domain': current_site.domain,
        'token': user.token
    })
    mail = EmailMessage(email_subject, html_message, to=[email])
    mail.content_subtype = "html"
    created = mail.send()
    if not created:
        return False
    return True

def verify_password_token(token):
    try:
        token = get_user_model().objects.get(token=token)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, get_user_model().DoesNotExist):
        return False
    if token is not None:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

my view only contains, if an email was found then send the email

```
 form = RequestRestoreCodeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if generate_password_reset_token(request, form.cleaned_data.get('email')):
```

Comment: Your `pre_save` signal generates a new token each time the user is saved, so doing `User.objects.create(email=user, token=user.token)` does not actually set the token to what you think since it's immediately replaced in the `pre_save` method. Also you probably shouldn't delete the `user`, just create a `reset_token` method on your user model to change the token.

Comment: Don't know what you're trying to do but reset password by delete user and create it again is not an acceptable practice at my point of view

Comment: how can  I a better way to fix this?

Comment: Just create a `reset_token` method on your `User` model to re-generate (and save) a new token without changing the user.

Comment: @dirkgroten `reset_token = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=False, unique=True, null=False)` like this or any other config?

Comment: no, a **method**, not a **field**.